# Disable reset in settings

Tags: settings, factory-reset

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9. I want to modify the Android to remove all applications and leave only the GPS. I managed to do it with adb, but when we reset the phone, everything comes back.

I would like to remove the reset option in the settings, but I don't know how.

I tried

```
adb shell pm disable com.android.settings.Settings$ResetDashboardFragmentActivity
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do mean `all applications`?  Does this include pre installed ones.

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell pm disable` does not uninstall but simply disables an installed app. And the information about which app is disabled is stored in your user data partition.

If you perform a factory reset the user data partition is reset to it's original state which effectively removes the information about disabled apps. This is by design on the Android system.

If an app can not be fully uninstalled it is a system or pre-installed app that is located on the system partition. And the system partition is read-only so you can not change it on an unrooted phone.

Only if you root your device and/or install a custom ROM you can uninstall and permanently uninstall pre-installed and system apps.